# Search function from two arrays with a for loop

Tags: c, arrays, search

I have been trying to create a search function for comparing two arrays. For the situation I'm working with I can't use strings, so I have been storing my text as arrays. No matter the function I'm searching for, the loop runs 7 times and then closes. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0, q = 6, z = 0, o;
    char text[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrsabdceg", a[] = " defgh";
    while (i != 1){
            if (a[1] == text[z]){
            for (int p=0; q > p; p++){
                  o = z+p;
                  printf(".");   //This is just here for debug
                  if (a[p] == text[o]){
                        printf("hmm\n");}
                  else {break;}
            }}
            z++;
            if (text[z]=='\n'){i = 1;}
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `if (a[0] == text[z])` to check if the first character is found?

Comment: Did you mean `if (text[z]==0){i = 1;}` to check for the end of the search string (whis is 0-terminated, not \n-terminated)
? Even better would be `while (text[z])`

Comment: Why is `q=4` while `a[]` holds 6 characters?

Comment: I'm trying to check if its the full correct occurance, the full program is a selection of random words mixed together, so I have to make sure its actually the correct word I've found, and I changed the length of a[] but forgot to update q

Comment: Why not use `strstr()`?